Largest subsequence of digits that form a prime?

Question
Given a list of digits 0-9 {d[[1]],d[[2]],...,d[[n]]}, I am interested in finding the largest subsequence of digits (largest when you IntegerJoin the digits together into an integer) that is prime in the list. I return -Infinity if no prime subsequence exists.
I am looking for ways to find this maximum prime subsequence in a faster manner.

Methods I've tried so far
Search all subsequences
The easiest method to write is to generate all subsequences, find which subsequences form a prime, and take the largest of those prime subsequences:
getMaxPrime0[nums_] := 
 With[{subs = FromDigits /@ Subsequences[nums]},
  Pick[subs, PrimeQ /@ subs] // Max
  ]

Search longest subsequences first
Since the maximal prime subsequence will also be one of the longest prime subsequences (even if there's leading zeros), it makes sense to search the longest subsequences first, instead of creating all possible subsequences at once.
So we start at the full length list and work our way down in subsequence length n until we find a prime with digit length n, and take the maximum:
getMaxPrime1[nums_] := Module[{n, cands, allNotPrime},
  n = Length@nums;

  (*subsequence candidates of length n. Note delayed evaluation so this updates when we call  
   it each time after decrementing n*)
  cands := FromDigits@# & /@ Subsequences[nums, {n}];

  (*determine if all the numbers aren't prime (returns True if all \
  aren't prime,and False if any are prime)*)
  allNotPrime := Nor @@ (PrimeQ@cands);

  (*decrease subsequence length until we find a prime,or hit n=
  0 (I.e.there are no prime subsequences)*)
  While[allNotPrime && n > 0, n-- ];

  (*If a prime subsequence exists,
  take the largest one. If no prime subsequence exists,returns -Infinity*)
 Pick[cands, PrimeQ /@ cands] // Max
  ]


Search longest subsequences first, only ending in 1,3,7,9
Since all primes (other than 2 and 5) end in 1,3,7 or 9, I thought a possible speed-up could come from only generating subsequences that end in these values.
I am aware that the ith through jth subsequence of length n can be found by using the third argument Subsequences[nums,n,{i,j}], but I am not sure how to specify a non-contiguous set of subsequences (I.e. the indices corresponding to where the n length subsequences would have to end to have last digit 1,3,7 or 9). Since I couldn't figure out how to do this, I just made my own code that gets those subsequences using Position :
candsThatEndWell[nums_, n_] := Module[{endIndices, longEnough},
  (* indices of good prime endings *)
  endIndices = Position[nums, 1 | 3 | 7 | 9] // Flatten;

  (*the indexes need to be far enough away from the first position \
s.t. an n-length subsequence can end there*)
  longEnough = Pick[endIndices, UnitStep[(n - 1) - endIndices], 0];

  (*create n-length integers*)
  FromDigits[nums[[# - (n - 1) ;; #]]] & /@ longEnough
  ]


And implemented a search similar to before that decreases in subsequence size until a prime is found:
getMaxPrime2[nums_] := Module[{n, cands}, 
  n = Length@nums;

  cands := candsThatEndWell[nums, n];

  While[AllTrue[cands, ! PrimeQ[#] &] && n > 0, n--];
  
  If[n > 0,
   Pick[cands, PrimeQ /@ cands] // Max,
   (*catch the 2 or 5 case by checking once over the individual \
   digits*)
   Cases[nums, 2 | 5] // Max
   ]
  ]

This did not, however, have any meaningful performance gain:
SeedRandom[1234];
nums = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, 1000];

getMaxPrime0[nums]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
getMaxPrime1[nums]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
getMaxPrime2[nums]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

(*48.0026*)
(*4.56614*)
(*4.4294*)


You can get a very small improvement by doing two things: reduce the number of prime checks and short circuit the loop.

I can shave off a few tenths of a second, but I think the bottleneck is PrimeQ[]. It's probably not possible to filter out nonprimes more efficiently than PrimeQ[], other than the base-10 filters you've already included.

It looks to me like the following is slightly faster on average, but don't know if it's enough for you.
getMaxPrimeAlt[nums_] :=
  Do[
    With[
      {prime = SelectFirst[ReverseSort[FromDigits /@ Subsequences[nums, {n}]], PrimeQ]},
      If[MissingQ[prime], Continue, Return[prime]]],
    {n, Length@nums, 1, -1}]

This suggests to me that as the sequence gets longer, sorting the longer subsequences is faster than testing primality on every element of the subsequence. So, when we find a prime relatively early, sorting first and selecting the first prime pays off.

Thanks! This tells me I need to be more careful in finding where my bottlenecks are.
Also kind of unrelated question, but I've always wondered is your name supposed to be (left)eric(right) or is that not what the l and r stand for?

@ydd The l and r are not left and right, but that would be kind of cool.

A refactoring of the OP's ideas, with an eye toward tuning the performance of things other than PrimeQ[], saves about 0.5 sec for me:
cTEW = Compile[{{seq, _Integer, 1}},
   (* return: 0 = skip, 1 = test for primality *)
   If[seq[[1]] == 0,(* leading digit 0 - skip *)
    0,
    Switch[Last@seq,(* last digits tests *)
     0, 0,
     2, 0,
     4, 0,
     5, 0,
     6, 0,
     8, 0,
     _, If[Mod[Total@seq, 3] == 0,
      0,
      1]]],
   Parallelization -> True, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
gMP[list_] :=
  Do[
   With[{seqs = Partition[list, len, 1]},
    With[{good = FromDigits /@ Pick[seqs, cTEW[seqs], 1]},
     With[{res = Max@Pick[good, PrimeQ /@ good]},
      If[res > 0, Return[res, Do]]
      ]]],
   {len, Length[list] - 1, 1, -1}];

SeedRandom[1234];
nums = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, 1000];

getMaxPrime2[nums]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
gMP[nums]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
(*
4.5913
4.07479
*)

